# Delete an item by id in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to delete a node by id in XML my code is this:

```
  $id=$_GET["id"];
  $usuarios= simplexml_load_file('cart.xml');
  if($_GET["action"] == "delete"){
    foreach($usuarios->carro as $elemento){
      if($elemento['id'] == $id) {
        echo '<script>alert("delete")</script>';
        unset($elemento['id']);
      }
    }
  }
```

but doesn't work.

My XML `cart.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
<carro id="0">
 <usuario>alex</usuario>
 <producto>instict</producto>
 <Size>CH</Size>
 <cantidad>1</cantidad>
 <precio>100</precio>
</carro>
<carro id="1">
 <usuario>alex</usuario>
 <producto>instict</producto>
 <Size>G</Size>
 <cantidad>1</cantidad>
 <precio>100</precio>
</carro>
<carro id="2">
 <usuario>alex</usuario>
 <producto>instict</producto>
 <Size>G</Size>
 <cantidad>1</cantidad>
 <precio>100</precio>
</carro>
<carro id="3">
 <usuario>Gera</usuario>
 <producto>instict</producto>
 <Size>M</Size>
 <cantidad>1</cantidad>
 <precio>100</precio>
</carro>
</info>
```

I want to delete for example `id="2"` so the output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
<carro id="0">
 <usuario>alex</usuario>
 <producto>instict</producto>
 <Size>CH</Size>
 <cantidad>1</cantidad>
 <precio>100</precio>
</carro>
<carro id="1">
 <usuario>alex</usuario>
 <producto>instict</producto>
 <Size>G</Size>
 <cantidad>1</cantidad>
 <precio>100</precio>
</carro>

<carro id="3">
 <usuario>Gera</usuario>
 <producto>instict</producto>
 <Size>M</Size>
 <cantidad>1</cantidad>
 <precio>100</precio>
</carro>
</info>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
`$usuarios->carro as $key => $elemento`

and then

`unset($usuarios->carro[$key]);`

and then write result in new file as string

`file_put_contents('newfile.xml', $usuarios->asXML());`

Comment: hi thanks for your answer i did what you say but is the same output here is my code                                                                                       
      $id=$_GET["id"];
      $usuarios= simplexml_load_file('cart.xml');
      if($_GET["action"] == "delete"){
        foreach($usuarios->carro as $key => $elemento){
          if($elemento['id'] == $id) {

               unset($usuarios->carro[$key]);
               file_put_contents('newfile.xml', $usuarios->asXML());
               echo '<script>alert("Encontrado")</script>';}}}